# What is java's equivalent of ManualResetEvent?

Tags: java, .net, multithreading, synchronization

What is java's equivalent of [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The closest I know of is the [Semaphore](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Just use it with a "permit" count of 1, and acquire/release will be pretty much the same as what you know from the `ManualResetEvent`.

> A semaphore initialized to one, and
> which is used such that it only has at
> most one permit available, can serve
> as a mutual exclusion lock. This is
> more commonly known as a binary
> semaphore, because it only has two
> states: one permit available, or zero
> permits available. When used in this
> way, the binary semaphore has the
> property (unlike many Lock
> implementations), that the "lock" can
> be released by a thread other than the
> owner (as semaphores have no notion of
> ownership). This can be useful in some
> specialized contexts, such as deadlock
> recovery.

Comment: I don't think this can work without a race condition (assuming a thread cannot release a semaphore it did not previously acquire itself)

Comment: I take it back - from the documentation it appears a semaphore can be released without ever taking it.

Comment: Yeah, that's because semaphores have no ownership notion. They are pretty much synchronized counters which have threads wait if the counter is 0.

Comment: If semaphore is released multiple times without proper aquire, then availiblePermits will be greater than 1 and it will not behave the same way as ManulResetEvent would since reset() will not cause the waitOne() to wait.

Comment: Once you `Set` a `ManualResetEvent` it's permanently open, all current and future `Wait`s will pass. `Semaphore` once `acquire`d to let one thread pass, will stop all other threads. Closest thing would be to call `release` immediately after each `acquire`, but that's still plenty of overhead and micro-blocking.

Comment: @Agent_L You're of course correct, there needs to be an immediate `release` for it to mimick the `ManualResetEvent`, otherwise you have a `AutoResetEvent`. As I wrote, this is just the closest sync primitive I'm aware of in Java. A common use of the `ManualResetEvent` is for one thread to wait for the synchronization, and that use-case will not suffer from micro-blocking (this would only happen if multiple threads wait at once at the event) and the overhead should be fairly small (comparable to the monitor solution offered in another answer).

Answer (score 28):

```
class ManualResetEvent {

  private final Object monitor = new Object();
  private volatile boolean open = false;

  public ManualResetEvent(boolean open) {
    this.open = open;
  }

  public void waitOne() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (monitor) {
      while (open==false) {
          monitor.wait();
      }
    }
  }

  public boolean waitOne(long milliseconds) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (monitor) {
      if (open) 
        return true;
      monitor.wait(milliseconds);
        return open;
    }
  }

  public void set() {//open start
    synchronized (monitor) {
      open = true;
      monitor.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void reset() {//close stop
    open = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it will not work at all: thread one calls `waitOne()` and blocks in `monitor.wait()`. Thread two calls `set` and blocks on `synchronized (monitor)`. This is the only use case, right? I think it's okay if you just leave out `synchronized` statement in `set`.

Comment: @LimitedAtonement: in Java you must be in a synchronized block in order to wait on an object. During the wait, the monitor lock of that object is released, so it can be acquired in another thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: @WayneUroda My bad. I guess I shouldn't ask you why one has to be in a `synchronized` block in order to then release the lock by calling `wait`. I'm sure that's as old as the hills ;) .

Comment: @LimitedAtonement in other languages you can wait/notify on similar entities without having to have them locked (C# IIRC, win32/GDI, etc). I think that it is done in java this way to help the programmer avoid some common race conditions. Maybe this can explain better than I can :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block

Comment: its work fine! and its correct implementation ManualResetEvent in java. All other implementation or bad or complex

Answer (score 10):

Try [CountDownLatch](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with count of one.

```
CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

Comment: The problem with CountDownLatch is that it's not reusable. Once the latch reaches 0, it can't be used anymore. It can be replaced with a new latch instance, but this can create race conditions unless done right.

Answer (score 3):

Based on:

> ManualResetEvent allows threads to communicate with each other by
>   signaling. Typically, this
>   communication concerns a task which
>   one thread must complete before other
>   threads can proceed.

from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx

you possibly want to look at the Barriers in the Java concurrency package - specifically **CyclicBarrier** I believe:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html

It blocks a fixed number of threads until a particular event has occured.  All the threads must come together at a **barrier point**.

Comment: can you provide some examples of that Barrier? I didn't get the example from documentation.

Comment: Oh, I've found an article: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/cyclicbarrier.html

So it blocks till all threads wil reach the barrier (so critical mass is formed) and then it shall continue. Quite isntersting. Now I'll know this thing. Unfortunately it's not so usefull for question, but it comes so, that each java Object has wait, shich is ManualResetEvent

Comment: @BogdanMart But it re-blocks automatically, which means it's neither `ManualResetEvent` nor `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: @BogdanMart I wasn't talking about other answers. I was talking about how your comment is not true and misleading other readers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the crux of the .NET MRE is thread affinity and its ability to let all waiting threads go through when Set is called. I found the use of the Semaphore works well. However, if I get 10 or 15 threads waiting, then I run into another issue. Specifically, it occurs when Set is called. In .Net, all waiting threads are released. Using a semphore does not release all. So I wrapped it in a class. NOTE: I am very familiar with .NET threading. I am relatively new to Java threading and synchronization. Nevertheless, I am willing to jump in and get some real feedback. Here's my implementation with assumptions that a Java novice would make:

```
public class ManualEvent {
private final static int MAX_WAIT = 1000;
private final static String TAG = "ManualEvent"; 
private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_WAIT, false);

private volatile boolean signaled = false;
public ManualEvent(boolean signaled) {
    this.signaled = signaled; 
    if (!signaled) {
        semaphore.drainPermits();
    }
}

public boolean WaitOne() {
    return WaitOne(Long.MAX_VALUE);
}

private volatile int count = 0;
public boolean WaitOne(long millis) {
    boolean bRc = true;
    if (signaled)
        return true;

    try {
        ++count;
        if (count > MAX_WAIT) {
            Log.w(TAG, "More requests than waits: " + String.valueOf(count));
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "ManualEvent WaitOne Entered");
        bRc = semaphore.tryAcquire(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        Log.d(TAG, "ManualEvent WaitOne=" + String.valueOf(bRc));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        bRc = false;
    }
    finally {
        --count;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "ManualEvent WaitOne Exit");
    return bRc;
}

public void Set() {
    Log.d(TAG, "ManualEvent Set");
    signaled = true;
    semaphore.release(MAX_WAIT);
}

public void Reset() {
    signaled = false;
    //stop any new requests
    int count = semaphore.drainPermits();
    Log.d(TAG, "ManualEvent Reset: Permits drained=" + String.valueOf(count));
}
```

}

Also note that I am basically betting that there's no more than a 1000 requests waiting for a release at any given time. By releasing and aquiring in batches, I am attempting to release any waiting threads. Note the call to WaitOne is working 1 permit at a time.