# Java's equivalent to .Net's AutoResetEvent?

Tags: java, events, concurrency, synchronization, autoresetevent

What should I use to get semantics equivalent to [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) in Java?
(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064596/what-is-javas-equivalent-of-manualresetevent) for ManualResetEvent).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@user249654's answer looked promising. I added some unit tests to verify it, and indeed it works as expected.

I also added an overload of `waitOne` that takes a timeout.

The code is here in case anyone else finds it useful:

#### Unit Test

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;

/**
 * @author Drew Noakes http://drewnoakes.com
 */
public class AutoResetEventTest
{
    @Test
    public void synchronisesProperly() throws InterruptedException
    {
        final AutoResetEvent event1 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        final AutoResetEvent event2 = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        final int loopCount = 10;
        final int sleepMillis = 50;

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                    {
                        long t = currentTimeMillis();
                        event1.waitOne();
                        Assert.assertTrue("Time to wait should be within 5ms of sleep time",
                                Math.abs(currentTimeMillis() - t - sleepMillis) < 5);
                        Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
                        t = currentTimeMillis();
                        event2.set();
                        Assert.assertTrue("Time to set should be within 1ms", currentTimeMillis() - t <= 1);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Assert.fail();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
                        long t = currentTimeMillis();
                        event1.set();
                        Assert.assertTrue("Time to set should be within 1ms", currentTimeMillis() - t <= 1);
                        t = currentTimeMillis();
                        event2.waitOne();
                        Assert.assertTrue("Time to wait should be within 5ms of sleep time",
                                Math.abs(currentTimeMillis() - t - sleepMillis) < 5);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Assert.fail();
                }
            }
        });

        long t = currentTimeMillis();

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        int maxTimeMillis = loopCount * sleepMillis * 2 * 2;

        thread1.join(maxTimeMillis);
        thread2.join(maxTimeMillis);

        Assert.assertTrue("Thread should not be blocked.", currentTimeMillis() - t < maxTimeMillis);
    }

    @Test
    public void timeout() throws InterruptedException
    {
        AutoResetEvent event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        int timeoutMillis = 100;
        long t = currentTimeMillis();
        event.waitOne(timeoutMillis);
        long took = currentTimeMillis() - t;
        Assert.assertTrue("Timeout should have occurred, taking within 5ms of the timeout period, but took " + took,
                Math.abs(took - timeoutMillis) < 5);
    }

    @Test
    public void noBlockIfInitiallyOpen() throws InterruptedException
    {
        AutoResetEvent event = new AutoResetEvent(true);

        long t = currentTimeMillis();
        event.waitOne(200);
        Assert.assertTrue("Should not have taken very long to wait when already open",
                Math.abs(currentTimeMillis() - t) < 5);
    }
}
```

#### AutoResetEvent with overload that accepts a timeout

```
public class AutoResetEvent
{
    private final Object _monitor = new Object();
    private volatile boolean _isOpen = false;

    public AutoResetEvent(boolean open)
    {
        _isOpen = open;
    }

    public void waitOne() throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (_monitor) {
            while (!_isOpen) {
                _monitor.wait();
            }
            _isOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public void waitOne(long timeout) throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (_monitor) {
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (!_isOpen) {
                _monitor.wait(timeout);
                // Check for timeout
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t >= timeout)
                    break;
            }
            _isOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public void set()
    {
        synchronized (_monitor) {
            _isOpen = true;
            _monitor.notify();
        }
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        _isOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Drew Noakes, isn't the function waitOne() supposed to return a boolean like in the C# version?

Comment: I like your answer, but would you have to make a boolean WaitOne() in order to mimic the one at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ? My proposition would be that it would return the _isOpen variable you have but the key idea is it will block the current thread until the signal is received. What do you think?

Comment: @Masterminder you are right. The boolean return value is only required on WaitOne(long timeout), because when the timeout occurs, the _isOpen attribute could still be false.

Comment: Shouldn't the `set` method invoke `_monitor.notifyAll()` in case there is more than one thread waiting the the `waitOne()` method?  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055584/1556915

Answer (score 6):

```
class AutoResetEvent {

  private final Object monitor = new Object();
  private volatile boolean open = false;

  public AutoResetEvent(boolean open) {
    this.open = open;
  }

  public void waitOne() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (monitor) {
      while (open == false) { 
        monitor.wait();
      }
      open = false; // close for other
    }

  }

  public void set() {
    synchronized (monitor) {
      open = true;
      monitor.notify(); // open one 
    }
  }

  public void reset() {//close stop
    open = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, but does it mean that one thread cannot call set the event if another is waiting? The thread that's waiting holds a lock on `monitor`, right?

Comment: Seems that I was wrong, and that the lock is released during the wait. See the similar comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055584/24874).

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get CyclicBarrier to work for my purposes.

Here is the C# code I was trying to reproduce in Java (it's just a demonstration program I wrote to isolate the paradigm, I now use it in C# programs I write to generate video in real time, to provide accurate control of the frame rate):

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace TimerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            t.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate { are.Set(); });
            t.Enabled = true;
            while (true)
            {
                are.WaitOne();
                Console.WriteLine("main");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Java code I came up with to do the same thing (using the CyclicBarrier class as suggested in a previous answer):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class TimerTest2 {
    static CyclicBarrier cb;

    static class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        private CyclicBarrier cb;
        public MyTimerTask(CyclicBarrier c) { cb = c; }

        public void run() { 
            try { cb.await(); } 
            catch (Exception e) { } 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cb = new CyclicBarrier(2);
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new MyTimerTask(cb), 1000, 1000);

        while (true) {
            try { cb.await(); } 
            catch (Exception e) { }
            System.out.println("main");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class AutoResetEvent {

  private volatile boolean _signaled;
  private ReentrantLock _lock;
  private Condition _condition;

  public AutoResetEvent(boolean initialState) {
    _signaled = initialState;
    _lock = new ReentrantLock();
    _condition = _lock.newCondition();
  }

  public void waitOne(long miliSecond) throws InterruptedException {
    _lock.lock();
    try {
      while (!_signaled)
        _condition.await(miliSecond, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      _signaled = false;
    } finally {
        _lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void waitOne() throws InterruptedException {
    _lock.lock();
    try {
      while (!_signaled)
        _condition.await();
      _signaled = false;
    } finally {
        _lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void set() {
    _lock.lock();
    try {
      _condition.signal();
      _signaled = true;
    } finally {
      _lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void reset() {
    _lock.lock();
    try {
      _signaled = false;
    } finally {
      _lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One more extension to the solution from the accepted answer in case you would like to know whether your wait finished with timeout or with event set (which is exactly what .NET AutoResetEvent does).

```
public boolean waitOne(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        try {
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (!isOpen) {
                monitor.wait(timeout);
                // Check for timeout
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - t >= timeout)
                    break;
            }

            return isOpen;
        }
        finally {
            isOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is either a CyclicBarrier or a CountDownLatch.

Comment: CountDownLatch helped a bit, but it's not exactly equivalent.

Come on StackOverflow - it's impossible nobody implemented this yet...