# Conditions vs objects wait/notify

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was reading about `Condition` objects and how they offer multiple wait-sets per object and also distinguishing which object or group of objects/threads get a specific signal.
Why doesn't a regular `Object` do that? E.g.

Instead of:

```
final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition();   
final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition();     

lock.lock();  
try {  
  while (count == items.length)  
     notFull.await();  
  items[putptr] = x;  
  if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;  
      ++count;  
   notEmpty.signal();
```

We do this:

```
final Object notFull  = new Object();     
final Object notEmpty = new Object();       

lock.lock();  
try {  
  while (count == items.length)  
     notFull.wait();  
  items[putptr] = x;  
  if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;  
      ++count;  
   notEmpty.notify();
```

Don't we still have multiple wait-sets and distinguish among notified threads?

Answer (score 3):

In your example you created 2 Conditions on one Lock. This is what you can't do with built-in synchronization - you had to use 2 Objects to get 2 conditions.

And your second code is broken because you did not get lock on notFull and notEmpty but call wait / notify - you'll get IllegalMonitorStateException.  But if you tried to lock them both you would see you cannot do that simultaneously. This is the difference

Comment: So it is just "saving" no of objects?

Comment: No, it's avoiding the deadlock caused by having to acquire two different monitors in the nested synchronized blocks.

Comment: @RalfH:`deadlock in nested synchronized`. Would it be possible to give an example of this?

Comment: @Jim Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365132/java-nested-synchronization-blocks ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `synchronize` first when calling `wait` or `notify`. When you need two different sets, you need two objects to sync on. The nested sync will give you deadlocks.

Comment: But with condition I would still need to `Condition` objects

Comment: Two conditions is OK, as long as you have to lock one lock object only, not two different locks. This is what you can't do with monitors.

Comment: There is quite a lot of Q&A on this topic here. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190545/java-wait-notify-and-synchronized-blocks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block, for eaxmple.

Answer (score 0):

It's not okay. You have to own monitor of the object to use its `notFull.wait()` method. Even if it was allowed it would still not release `lock`, so no other thread could access it.