# Is it required to use thread wait() and notify() inside a synchronized block?

Tags: java, concurrency, wait, notify

In Java, is it required to use thread `wait()` and `notify()` within a `synchronized` block?

Comment: This question is confusing because if you are going to use wait() it must be inside a synchronized block, but if you are going to use a synchronized block it is not mandatory to have a wait/notify, which situation is the one you are asking about?

Comment: When the threads need to pass data around, it’s not enough to say “don’t run on the same data
while I am running” but each thread must tell another thread that “I have some data for you”.
In this case we require thread wait and notify. So synchronized behavior is different from wain/notify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Java will automatically ensure the marked section is entered by one and only one thread.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

see also this question: [java: wait(), notify() and synchronized blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190545/java-wait-notify-and-synchronized-blocks?rq=1)

---

Hmm.. seems to be some language issues.

You are not required to use wait and notify in a synchronized block, but if you want to use wait and notify, they must be used within a synchronized block.

Answer (score 2):

in short, [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811803/threadwait-and-notify). The thread must own the object's monitor before calling wait or notify.