# A query regarding Java Threads

Tags: java

Please let me know how I can print “After wait”; how can I notify main thread in the following code:

```
import java.util.*;  

public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList(6);
            al.add(0, "abc");
        al.add(1, "abc");
        al.add(2, "abc");
        synchronized(al){
            System.out.println("Before wait");
            al.wait();
            System.out.println("After wait");
        }       

      }

}
```

Comment: As the other answers explain more fully, `wait()` is not a sleep call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wait()` call is blocking until someone `notify()`s it... Basically, you would need to create a new thread that calls `al.notify()` when the main thread is blocking in `wait()`.

This program prints `Before wait`, pauses for one second, and prints `After wait`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        final ArrayList al = new ArrayList(6);
        al.add(0, "abc");
        al.add(1, "abc");
        al.add(2, "abc");

        // Start a thread that notifies al after one second.
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                synchronized (al) {
                    al.notify();      // <-- this "releases" the wait.
                }
            }
        }.start();

        synchronized (al) {
            System.out.println("Before wait");
            al.wait();
            System.out.println("After wait");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is a link to one of my previous answers, explaining why `wait()` and `notify()` *must* be executed while holding the lock of the monitor.

- [Why must wait() always be in synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block/2779674#2779674)

Comment: you have to add try catch around the al.wait() as well... but other than that, it's perfect. :)

Comment: No, the OP already has `throws InterruptedException` in the main method.

Comment: So, the wait-notify works only if your thread is having the object monitor. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You're not creating any other threads, so it's hard to see how there *is* anything else to notify the main thread. However, if you *did* have another thread which had a reference to `al`, you'd use something like:

```
synchronized(al) {
    al.notify();
}
```

or

```
synchronized(al) {
    al.notifyAll();
}
```

(The difference between the two is that `notify` will only wake a *single* thread from waiting; `notifyAll` will wake *all* the threads waiting on that object.)