# what will happen if i call wait method on object outside of synchronisation block?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why wait should always be in synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block)

What will happen if I call wait() and  notify(), notifyAll() method outside of synchronization ?
Does it has any effect ?

example

```
Class Test(){
 Test(){
```

I know I am writing empty try catch

```
   try{
      wait(); 
      notify();
      notifyAll();
   }catch (Exception ex)
  }
}
```

Comment: and what happens when you tried it?

Comment: If you have an empty catch block, you'll never know what happens. Never write empty catch blocks.

Comment: @Jesper: Well, currently there isn't even an empty block. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You get an [IllegalMonitorStateException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29),

> IllegalMonitorStateException - if the
>   current thread is not the owner of the
>   object's monitor.

Comment: it is working fine ! I checked . But why ?

Comment: @Nilesh Salpe, You can't wait/notify on a object you haven't locked because that is how the lock is designed to work.