# wait(), notify() and notifyAll() inside synchronized statement

Tags: java, synchronization

I get following error when trying to do invoke `notifyAll()` inside a synchronized statement: **Invoked Object.notify() outside synchronized context.**

Example:

```
final List list = new ArrayList();
synchronized(list) {..... invoked notifyAll() here};
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the question a bit more? What did you invoke notifyAll() on? Was it on the list object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why must wait() always be in synchronized block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-must-wait-always-be-in-synchronized-block)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only call `wait()`, `notify()`, and `notifyAll()` on the object that is being synchronized on:

```
synchronized (list) {
    //...
    list.notifyAll();
}
```

In other words, the calling thread must own the object's monitor.

If, inside `synchronized (list)`, you call `notifyAll()`, you are actually calling `notifyAll()` on `this` rather than `list`.

Comment: @Final Illusion: No problem. I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are calling `notifyAll()` on a different object, one for which you don't hold a lock. In your example, you may call `notifyAll()` on `list`, but not on `this`.

Answer (score 1):

A thread must own the lock on the object it's invoking wait, notify, notifyAll on. In the code you posted, the thread owns the lock on 'list' and then it calls notifyAll on 'this' object.