# Java Objects monitors

Tags: java, multithreading

I read that:

```
Object sync = new Object();

/* inter to monitor */
try {
    sync.wait();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {

} finally {

}

/* our code*/
/* exit from monotir */
sync.notify();
```

is like

```
synchronize (sync) {
    /* our code*/
}
```

Does it true?

I try this in my code and it doesn't work.

```
private Object data;
    private Object sync = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleProducerConsumer pc = new SimpleProducerConsumer();
        new Thread(pc.new Producer()).start();
        new Thread(pc.new Consumer()).start();
    }

    public Object pop() {
        try {
            sync.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Before");
        Object d = data;
        data = null;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("pop");
        System.out.println("After");
        sync.notify();
        return d;
    }

    public void push(Object d) {
        try {
            sync.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data = d;
        System.out.println("push");
        sync.notify();
    }

    class Producer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                push(new Object());
            }
        }
    }

    class Consumer implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                pop();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `sync.wait()` and `sync.notify()` are far from synonyms to `sychronize (sync) { ...` and `... }`.

In fact, in order to call `wait` you *have* to be in a `synchronized` block.

I'll explain the concepts of `synchronize`, `wait` and `notify` and the difference will be clear.

- When a thread enters a `synchronized (sync) { ... }` block it grabs the lock of the `sync` monitor (meaning that the lock is taken and that no other thread can enter the block at that point).
- When a thread calls `sync.wait()` it temporarily releases the lock of `sync`. (It's *waiting* for something to happen. Something that requires the lock to be able to happen.)
- A thread calls `sync.notify()` to *notify* other threads that something *has happened*, at which point they resume execution.

> *What is wrong with my code?*

I assume you for instance want to make sure that if two threads try to pop something they should avoid doing the following:

```
Thread 1              Thread 2
--------------------------------------
Object d = data;
                      Object d = data;
                      data = null;
data = null;
return d;
                      return d;
```

To avoid this you need to make sure that `d = data` and `data = null` happens *atomically*.

This can be achieved by doing

```
Object d;
synchronized (sync) {
    d = data;
    data = null;
}
```

(Now the first and second statement in Thread 1 above can't be split up.)

Furthermore you seem to want `pop` to be blocking, i.e. if `d == null` it should wait for some other thread to `push` something.

This can be achieved by doing

```
synchronized (sync) {
    while (d == null)
        sync.wait();
}
```

and do `sync.notify()` in `push` (again within a `synchronized` block covering everything that needs to be done atomically in the push method).

**Related question / further reading:**

- [The Java™ Tutorials: Guarded Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)
- [Why must wait() always be in synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block)

  My answer over here gives an example of what could happens in a producer / consumer situation if `wait` and `notify` where allowed to be called *outside* a synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

You have both your `push()` and `pop()` methods waiting on the same lock object for a `notify()`, but there's no one that calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on that object, so they're waiting indefinitely.
What happens here is:

1. the Producer waits on the `sync.wait()` call inside `push()` for someone to call `sync.notify()`
2. the Consumer waits on the `sync.wait()` call inside `pop()` for someone to call `sync.notify()`
3. deadlock

Answer (score 1):

No, they're completely different.  You call `wait()` from inside a `synchronized` block, if you want to suspend execution until some condition is met.  You use `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the same object, (again in a `synchronized` block) once that condition is met.

So in this circumstance, two threads can actually be in `synchronized` blocks on the same object at the same time; this is allowed when one of them has done a `wait()`.  The first thread starts up again once the second thread exits the `synchronized` block in which it called `notify()`.