# cannot understand the synchronized in this program

Tags: java, wait, synchronized

I cannot understand why we need to `synchronized` the `wait()` method. I can get `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` after I removed this synchronized block. 
http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ315_021.htm

Comment: Read this to find out more about synchronization http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html?m=1 you must be clear when you ask questions... Search google a little deeper before posting here man otherwise people will -1 you as you can see lol

Comment: @Savlon: I know about synchronization. But I cannot understand why there are multiple threads accessing this method.

Comment: @Savlon: Can you point out which threads access this method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block

This question covers it pretty well in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is: `wait()` has to be in synchronized block. We can refer to: [Why must wait() always be in synchronized block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block), answered by AnthonyM