# Issue with wait();

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I currently have this run method that I would like 3 seperate threads to access and wait for another thread to notify.

```
public void run(){
   try {
      System.out.println(this.name + " waits on the table...");
      /// waits for agent to signal that new ingredients have been passed out
      wait();
   } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
   System.out.println(this.name + " stops waiting and checks the table...");
   checkTable();
}
```

Currently this throws a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` which can be solved by using synchroize on the method. The problem is that when I use synchroize the first thread will wait and the other two threads can't do anything since the first thread has a lock on the method. So my question is how can i make it so that three separate threads can access this method and wait at the same time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why wait should always be in synchronized block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1) you have to [own the monitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2).
[You acquire the ownership by using `synchronize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1).
In you case `synchronize(this)`.

But to block 3 threads and release them from a 4th, you may use [`java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or a [`java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) as mentioned by [Perception](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680925/perception)

Here is a version with CyclicBarrier:

```
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class RendezVous extends Thread {

   private final CyclicBarrier _barrier;

   RendezVous( String name, CyclicBarrier barrier ) {
      super( name );

      _barrier = barrier;
      setDaemon( true );
      start();
   }

   @Override public void run() {
      System.out.println( getName() + " waits for counterparts..." );
      try { _barrier.await(); }
      catch( InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException x ) {
         x.printStackTrace(); }
      System.out.println( getName() + " has reached its rendez-vous!");
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
      CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier( 4 );
      new RendezVous( "Rdvz 1", barrier ); Thread.sleep(  1000L );
      new RendezVous( "Rdvz 2", barrier ); Thread.sleep(  1000L );
      new RendezVous( "Rdvz 3", barrier ); Thread.sleep(  1000L );
      new RendezVous( "Rdvz 4", barrier ); Thread.sleep( 10000L );
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Rdvz 1 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 2 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 3 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 4 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 4 has reached its rendez-vous!
Rdvz 1 has reached its rendez-vous!
Rdvz 2 has reached its rendez-vous!
Rdvz 3 has reached its rendez-vous!
```

And a version with CountDownLatch:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class CountDownLatchDemo extends Thread {

   private final CountDownLatch _cdl;

   CountDownLatchDemo( String name, CountDownLatch cdl ) {
      super( name );

      _cdl = cdl;
      setDaemon( true );
      start();
   }

   @Override public void run() {
      System.out.println( getName() + " waits for counterparts..." );
      try {
         _cdl.countDown();
         _cdl.await();
      }
      catch( InterruptedException x ) {
         x.printStackTrace(); }
      System.out.println( getName() + " has reached its rendez-vous!");
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
      CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch( 4 );
      new CountDownLatchDemo( "Rdvz 1", cdl ); Thread.sleep(  1000L );
      new CountDownLatchDemo( "Rdvz 2", cdl ); Thread.sleep(  1000L );
      new CountDownLatchDemo( "Rdvz 3", cdl ); Thread.sleep(  1000L );
      new CountDownLatchDemo( "Rdvz 4", cdl ); Thread.sleep( 10000L );
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Rdvz 1 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 2 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 3 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 4 waits for counterparts...
Rdvz 4 has reached its rendez-vous!
Rdvz 1 has reached its rendez-vous!
Rdvz 2 has reached its rendez-vous!
Rdvz 3 has reached its rendez-vous!
```

Comment: A count down latch would be a better choice for the OP's scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the very deatlied answer I ended up using a countdown latch. It always fun to learn about useful classes that i had no idea about before.

Comment: Thanks for the check! For my own, I prefer CyclicBarrier but both are adapted.

Answer (score 0):

When the first thread goes to wait it releases the lock. So other threads can acquire the lock