# Illegal State Monitor Exception in distributed system

Tags: java, distributed-computing

this is my code. It's supposed to implement a way of synchronizing calls in a distributed system. This is the part where i send the message and wait for acks. The network and the peers are supposed reliable.

My problem though is related to local sync, because it keeps raising this exception and i cannot understand why.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
at distributed.PeerManager.sendAllWithAck(PeerManager.java:212)
at distributed.TokenManager.onTokenReceived(TokenManager.java:67)
at communication.TokenMessage.execute(TokenMessage.java:21)
at distributed.ListenThread.run(ListenThread.java:38)
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at distributed.AckWaiter.run(AckWaiter.java:74)
```

Here's the AckWaiter class:

```
public class AckWaiter extends Thread {
    public int counter;
    PeerManager pm;
    Message m;
    public Object waiter;
    public int parentPort;

    public AckWaiter(PeerManager pm, Message m, int n,int parentPort) {
        counter = n;
        this.pm = pm;
        this.m = m;
        this.parentPort=parentPort;
        waiter=new Object();
    }

    public synchronized void notifyAck() {
        counter--;
            notify();

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        pm.sendAllExceptMe(m);

        try {
            BufferedReader inFromClient=new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(pm.listener.socketMap.get(parentPort).getInputStream()));
            while(counter>0){
                    wait(100);
                    Message m=CustomMarshaller.getCustomMarshaller().unmarshal(inFromClient.readLine());
                    if(m==null){
                        continue;
                    }
                    m.execute(pm);
                }
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 


        waiter.notify();
        return;
    }
}
```

and here's the call supposed to block the thread

```
public synchronized void sendAllWithAck(Message m){
    if(aw!=null){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    aw=new AckWaiter(this,m,connectionList.size()-1,m.sender.getPort());
    aw.start();
    try {
        aw.waiter.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    aw=null;
}
```

'sendAllWithAck' should  start a AckWaiter Thread, wait on the object 'waiter' that will be notified when i receive 'n' ACKs.

The 'notifyAck' method is called by the communication layer when an ACK message is received.

AckWaiter is a thread on his own because 'sendAllWithAck' could be called by a thread in charge of reading from a socket. I have n peers and every peer has an open socket (with a Thread handling inbound messages) for every other peer, so if i wait for ACKs in response to a message received, i wouldn't be able to read  the ACK from that one peer (parentPort is the identifier of that peer so i can periodically check for ACKs inside this thread).

I'm open to modify my architecture if this exception is due to a structural problem but i have no idea to handle it differently without modify my communication layer, and that would be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Methods `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` must be in `synchronized` block. And run method is only accessed by one thread (so it doesn't need to be synchronized) and exception was in ListenThread.

Comment: they are all in synchronized methods

Comment: You don't synchronize von your `waiter` while notify/wait. You synchronize on your object which is what the `synchonized` keyword means.

Comment: I know how synchronization work but still can't understand why does this matter. I have to wait on 2 different objects because one is "wait until an ack is received so that i can evaluate how many acks are left" and the other, when i wait on 'waiter', means "wait untl i've received all the acks"

Comment: Just check on which object is synchronization and change if needed to one on which all synchronization is done. Use debugger if stackTrace is not understandable.

Comment: You're not helping because you're not explaining the reason why the exception is raised. You're just throwing statements that i can't connect to my problem.

Comment: @Chobeat you don't know how it works. Get yourself a good book (Concurrency in practice is the best read imho) and you may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-wait-should-always-be-in-synchronized-block for your specific question.

Comment: I know how it works. I studied how it works at uni, i studied how it works on the  Oracle docs and i've used object sync like a thousand time in Java. Still i can't understand what that dude is saying.

Comment: I'm gonna check that post anyway, maybe it will help

Comment: Ok got what you were saying. Now the exception is not raised anymore but still not working. I need some time to check. Thanks for now