# Unexpected IllegalStateMonitorException

Tags: java, multithreading

Sometimes the below code throws IllegalStateMonitorException and sometimes it runs nicely. Not able to understand the scenarios how could it happen as it is always called under lock.lock().

Full Code:

```
public class OddEvenPrinter implements Runnable {
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition conditionFlag = lock.newCondition();
    private int counter = 0;

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i<1000;i++){
            printEven();
            printOdd();
        }
    }

    private void printEven() {
        try{
            lock.lock();
            while(counter%2!=0){
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" thread printing Even :"+counter);
            counter++;
            conditionFlag.signalAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void printOdd(){
        try{
            lock.lock();
            while(counter%2==0){
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" thread printing Odd :"+counter);
            counter++;
            conditionFlag.signalAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        OddEvenPrinter counter = new OddEvenPrinter();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(counter);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(counter);
        t1.setName("First");
        t2.setName("Second");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be calling `wait()` without using a `synchronized` block. I'm surprised that *ever* works.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772236/illegal-monitor-state-exception and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537116/illegalmonitorstateexception-on-wait-call and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126550/java-wait-and-notify-illegalmonitorstateexception   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758731/illegal-state-monitor-exception-in-distributed-system

Comment: I think you might be looking for Condition.await()  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--

Comment: Instead of synchronized, using reentrantLock and calling wait() only after calling lock() on reentrant lock. So ideally it should work.

Comment: ah..i got it. My bad :(

Comment: @javaq: But you're calling `wait` on the instance of `OddEvenCounter`, which you *don't* have the monitor for... that's entirely separate from the `Lock` you've created. I'm still trying to work out why it isn't throwing most of the time..