# Is wait(1) in a non-blocking while(true)-loop more efficient than using wait() and notify()?

Tags: java, loops, wait, nonblocking, notify

Does a `while(true)` Java loop together with `wait(1)` use more or less resources than a blocking loop with `wait()` and `notify()`?

And do the CPU cores have some special (hardware) implementations to allow `wait(1)`? If yes, are there any limitations while working with such non-blocking loops?

An example:

```
while(true){
    wait(1);
    //do the job here...
}
```

(Just a note: Without the `wait(1)` a core would go radical 100% in a `while(true)` loop...)

Comment: Well, `wait(1)` is really "wait one millisecond." A millisecond is a very long time in terms of CPU process clocks, so the CPU basically gets to rest for a whole millisecond every... however long it takes to process `while(true)`.

Comment: Did you check how long it actually waits? It might be around 20ms since all those times are "at least" and depend on the OS and what scheduling accuracy it provides.

Comment: That's correct, in the end it's all up to the hardware and the OS. But it's the only way to go. I mean: blocking won't be faster, right?

Comment: You can't block a CPU core entirely, OS thread scheduler will still run it's own tasks (e.g. thread scheduling) with a higher priority than whatever you do even without any `wait` (or better `Thread.yield()`). Your code is a guest that may provide hints to the system but it is free to stop your thread, save it's context and continue later at any given time.

Comment: Run as many threads as your machine can handle using the wait(1) method, and then compare with using a wait(Integer.MAX_VALUE). What do you see?

Comment: @zapl: So you mean that `wait(1)` may use even more time than just `wait()` and `notify()`? Okey, you got me, now I really need to test it. ;)

Comment: I don't know how a loop with  wait and notify would look like :) And I would usually not use wait / notify because there are much nicer synchronization utilities in util.concurrent and things like blocking queues and much more so I never needed a loop that waits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As to the original question of why `while (true);` takes up more CPU than `while (true) { wait(1); }`, consider: a modern CPU can perform billions of instructions per second. With the `wait(1)` loop, assuming it is perfect and waits exactly one millisecond each time, you're limiting the CPU to **one thousand instructions** per second. Without it, there's no limit and it can run the tight loop **billions of times per second** instead.

As to the new question of which is more efficient, the `while (true) { wait(1); }` approach vs. `wait()` and being `notify()`ed...

Well let's say you're waiting on a condition. Option one:

```
while (true) {
    wait(1);
    if (condition()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
wait();
```

and elsewhere:

```
//code which causes condition() to be true
notify();
```

Say it takes 10 seconds for condition to be true. In the first approach, you call `wait(1)` 10,000 times and check `condition()` 10,000 times. In the second approach, you call `wait()` once and `notify()` once.

Comment: Not millions, billions!

Comment: @waTeim: it's quadrillions isn't it?

Comment: I slightly changed the question. Maybe you'd like to improve your answer?

Comment: @Marcus: Well sure it's going to be more efficient to `wait()`, and then get notified when a condition changes, vs. doing `wait(1)` over and over and polling for the condition.

Comment: I also want to point out that `wait(1)` could be slower because `notify()` and `wait()` may use MUCH LESS than 1 millisecond...

Comment: @Marcus: You really need to supply a use-case here.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a trick question?

When you put a "wait()" into a loop, it releases the synchronization variable, allowing some other thread to go forward and eventually notify back to this thread that it can continue.  The thread won't proceed, and won't use any cpu cycles, until it gets that notify.   And that's why wait/notify must be called from within sync'd blocks or methods (not clear if you are doing that here).

By contrast, a "while ... true" is an infinite loop which is going to use every cpu cycle you give it, until the end condition is met.

I recommend a good book on Java threads and synchronization, like [http://www.amazon.com/Multithreaded-Programming-Java-Technology-Lewis/dp/0130170070](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130170070)

Answer (score 0):

It does use more resources, and in general is not a good design. You are far better off waiting properly as even if you don't get better performance in one specific test on one specific hardware you will get better performance in other suggestions.

This will become especially important if you have a lot of these threads running as the overhead is per thread.

Comment: Do you have any proves, test cases aso., that it uses more resources? Well, it's clear that blocking thread use less CPU resources, but also more time...so I'm not that sure if it uses more resources after all (considering that a prolonged time during a cache is filled is also a waste and could be used for other threads).

Answer (score -1):

Basically, Claudiu is right: CPU are very fast indeed.

But there is also another factor to consider: Actually `wait(1)` is ***always*** needed in non-blocking threads to allow other threads to continue. Because if there is no wait at all, the OS can't allocate resources to any other thread and they will starvate. On the other side, `wait(1)` *could* in reality cause a much longer wait depending how the OS allocates the resources. But that's up to the OS.

When programming, there are always 2 factors to consider:

*1. the amount of cache/RAM, and*

*2. the time needed for a thread/process.*

Therefore it's all about the **amount of resources used PER TIME: MB/s** (or in general: Bytes/s). You can't only make the right decisions based on the allocated resources as many programmers intend to do. It's even possible be that above non-blocking floop uses a lot less resources than a blocking one, because there is no synchronisation overhead. So never forget the time dimension.

*Conclusion:* Faster, non-blocking programs (can) use less resources.

Comment: "Because if there is no wait at all, the OS can't allocate resources to any other thread and they will starvate" Thats not the case. The keyword here is *premptive scheduling* which is pretty much the norm for general a purpose OS. What happens is that the available processor time is allocated evenly (with regards to constraints like priority) between the threads that are *ready* to run. Of course not consuming cpu time (through waiting) does increase the portion of cpu time allocated to the other threads, because the waiting thread is giving up the share of cpu time it would get while running

Comment: Okey, thanks for the hint. After all I'm not sure anymore if using `wait(1)` is more efficient than `wait()`and `notify()`. If you know it, feel free to write an answer and I will accept it.