# In Java, is it safe to lock and synchronize on the same object?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am building a concurrent application in Java. To avoid exposing my lock object externally, I have a `private` `final` lock object:

```
 private final Object Lock = new Object();
```

I use the lock for synchronization between threads:

```
synchronized (Lock) {

    // Do stuff
}
```

I *also* use the lock to wait for conditions:

```
while (conditionIsNotMet) {

    Lock.wait();
}
```

Does using the same object for both concurrency patterns cause any issues? Is there anything I should watch out for when doing this?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You need to have both for the `wait()` to work.

Comment: I need `synchronized` to use `wait()`?

Comment: Try to call `wait()` outside of a `synchronized` block. What happens?

Comment: You realize that your lock Object isn't declared `static`, right?

Comment: @sstan Thanks (for answer see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-must-wait-always-be-in-synchronized-block) @Powerlord Why would I want it to be `static`?

Comment: @sstan - Disagree that this is a duplicate.  Why must wait() be in a synchronized block is a different question from using a particular Lock for more than one purpose - in this case protecting a condition and simultaneously synchronizing for different purposes.

Comment: @Andy: Valid point. But, in the end, OP himself closed the question as a duplicate.

Comment: This is a difficult one. The button says "This answered my question", which it did, so I clicked it. However, I agree that the "duplicate" is actually a different (but related) question. Ask on meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to use a Lock for more than one purpose.  Generally, you should associate a Lock with your condition, and another for synchronizing access to shared data.  That said, nothing prevents you from doing this.

Update: That said, you should note @sstan comment - you do need to lock the Lock prior to waiting on it.  If you're also using the Lock elsewhere where it's *not* associated with the condition, you're asking for a deadlock.