# If I (need to) enclose wait() and notify() calls in synchronized blocks, how can notify() ever be executed?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I thought I would understand the concept of concurrency in Java, but now there is one thing which breaks my understanding:

Why do I have to enclose calls to wait() and notify() methods in synchronized blocks?

Assuming I have two threads: Thread A and Thread B. Also I have an object which I will use as a lock.
Now at some point in time, Thread A calls `wait()` on the object and is blocked afterwards until some other thread calls `notify()` on the same object. This was my understanding so far and this is fine. But now it sais that I need to enclose those calls in blocks synchronized on this object - indeed, I get an `IllegalMonitorStateException` if I do not do this. If I add these blocks, it works fine - but why??

I would have expected, that if I use these synchronized blocks, then Thread A will keep the lock on the object forever, because the `wait()` method keeps on running and Thread B just could not execute `notify()`, because it could not acquire the lock on the object, as it is still owned by thread A.

However, as I said, in reality it works fine, Thread B can execute `notify()` which unblocks Thread A ... Can someone please explain me exactly what happens here? How can Thread B acquire the lock?

Comment: Read the javadoc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--: *The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits [...]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How

When you call `wait` in the synchronized block, the monitor lock will be released automatically, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()):

> The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another
>   thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up
>   either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method.
>   The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor
>   and resumes execution.

After the other thread calling `notify` and exiting its `synchronized` block, the waiting thread will wake up and try aquire the monitor lock to continue.

### Why

Breifly:

> A wait() only makes sense when there is also a notify(), so it's
>   always about communication between threads, and that needs
>   synchronization to work correctly.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-must-wait-always-be-in-synchronized-block) for more.

Comment: Ah, thanks, now I get it! So it is just a special behavior of the wait() method that it can release the lock while being still inside the synchronized block - and basically after it starts waiting the lock is free and can be taken by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

**BottomLine**:
Invocation of `wait` method actually makes a thread "release its lock" and then suspend.

When `wait` is invoked, the Thread  A releases the lock and suspends execution. At some future time, Thread B will acquire the same lock and invoke `Object.notifyAll`, informing all threads(including Thread A) waiting on that lock that something important has happened. or `Object.notify`, informing a random thread(Thread A, if it is the only thread waiting on the object) from threads waiting on that lock that something important has happened.

Some time after the second Thread B has released the lock(when it exists the synchronized block), the first Thread A reacquires the lock and resumes by returning from the invocation of `wait`.