# How to fix IllegalMonitorStateException when using wait and notify?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have a JPanel class which starts another thread using "implements runnable". This other thread will then at various points call a method in the JPanel class which on doing so will then need to wait for the user input. I have attempted to implement it like this:

Method in JPanel class called by other thread that needs to wait:

```
public void methodToWait()
{
    while(conditionIsMet)
    {
        try
        {
            wait();
        }
        catch
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Method in JPanel class that notifies on wait on user input:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
{
    notifyAll();
}
```

However, upon running the application it throws a "java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException" upon calling the wait, why is it doing this and how do I resolve the issue?

Comment: If you don't know _why_ Java forces you to lock a mutex before calling `o.wait()`, then you probably could learn something from this tutorial:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the doc of [`wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()), [`notify`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) and [`notifyAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()):

> Thorws IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the
>   owner of the object's monitor.

That means you can not call them until you have aquired the monitor lock, in other words, until you have entered the [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) block or synchronized method(check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-must-wait-always-be-in-synchronized-block) for more).

---

Another important thing is, you should synchronize on the same object.

- When you use *synchronized block* with an explict object, you should call `wait` and `notify` on this object.
- When you use *synchronized method*, you are implictly synchronizing on `this`, so you should call `this.wait()` and `this.notify()`(keyword `this` is not mandory).

---

In this case, you need create an `Object` as monitor lock and share it between different classes.

---

Compliant example:

```
synchronized (obj) {
    while (<condition does not hold>)
        obj.wait();
    ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
}

synchronized (obj) {
    ... // Prepare the condition
    obj.notifyAll();
}
```

Noncompliant example:

```
void waitMethod() {
    wait(); // throws IllegalMonitorStateException  
}

void notifyMethod() {
    notify(); // throws IllegalMonitorStateException  
}
```

Noncompliant example:

```
synchronized (obj1) {
    while (<condition does not hold>)
        obj1.wait();
    ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
}

synchronized (obj2) {
    ... // call notifyAll on obj2 will not stop the wait on obj1
    obj2.notifyAll();
}
```

Noncompliant example:

```
in class1
synchronized void waitMethod() {
    while(someCondition()) {
        wait(); 
    }
}

in class2
synchronized void notifyMethod() {
    notify(); // call notifyAll on class2 will not stop the wait on class1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the exception has stopped but the notifyAll is not stopping the wait. Is it because the mouseClicked event is in a seperate "class"? In that it's under:
    this.table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()

Comment: @Jason That's right. You need synchronize on the same object. You can create an `Object` for synchonization and share this object in different classes.

Comment: Thank you so much, don't know why it took me two attempts to understand that as it seems so simple now!

Comment: @Jason Glad to help :)