# Certification practice exam on timed wait

Tags: java, concurrency, wait

Why is the second answer correct?  What exception was thrown and why?

[image: wait*emphasized text*]

P.S. Thanks for the answer!

Now I see that `t1.wait()` shall be inside `synchronized(t1)` - on t1, the same instance used to call wait(). Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779484/why-must-wait-always-be-in-synchronized-block) was helpful.

[image]

This is a *free* test taken from [here](https://www.iexamonline.com/exams/ocjp-certification-practice-online)

Comment: you call `t1.wait()`  without holding a lock on `t1` object so exception `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown.

Comment: You can just compile it and see for yourself.

Comment: But go() instance method is synchronized, meaning I call wait() from a synchronized block - doesn't it prevent IllegalMonitorStateException ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this code calls `t1.wait` without holding the lock on `t1` object - the `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown - as is documented in [`Object::wait(time)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)) method. This is a `RuntimeException` so it does not have to be specified in method signature. `synchronized` on `Bees::go` method will make sure that thread invoking this method will hold lock on `Bees` object - not `t1` object.